# How to connect spark-shell to Mesos?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mesos, mesosphere

I am trying to set up Apache Spark to run on Mesos, but I get the following message on terminal:

> W0309 10:37:10.570291  4017 sched.cpp:700] Ignoring framework registered message because it was sent from 'master@127.0.1.1:5050' instead of the leading master 'master@127.0.0.1:5050'

This message keeps appearing on the spark-shell and I am not able to run any command. I started spark-shell using the command:

```
./bin/spark-shell --master mesos://127.0.0.1:5050 --conf spark.executor.uri=/home/user/spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
```

When I check the Framework tab on Mesos WebUI, Spark Shell is listed as a framework.

Any idea on why I faced the above message and cannot run commands from spark-shell? Or, any good reference to run Spark on Mesos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be doing a bit of quess work here but I'm assuming you did not specify an `--ip` parameter when starting `mesos-master.sh`. In such case you should change your startup script to:

`./bin/spark-shell --master mesos://127.0.1.1:5050 --conf spark.executor.uri=/home/user/spark/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`

I'm guessing you have a `127.0.1.1` entry in your `/etc/hosts` (or whichever file is used for that resolution on your system) and Mesos is resolving to `127.0.1.1` by default. You can use the `ip` parameter to change it to `127.0.0.1` if you prefer for some reason.